# Not able to see mouse icon on text editing screen Remote desktop connection manager

Tags: rdc-manager

I have changed my laptop from HP to Dell laptop (Latitude E7470) recently. I have a secondary screen (Samsung S24D300) which I use for remote desktop connection manager (v2.7).
Everything was working fine with HP but after moving to Dell laptop now when I open RDCMan in the secondary screen, I am not able to see my mouse icon in the text editing area. Whether it is notepad, notepad++, powershell ISE etc. I have already checked and updated all video, BIOS drivers but the issue is still there. I am using windows 10 (Version 1709). Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Luckily I found the solution myself. the issue was with windows update, I was on windows 10 build 1703.
I upgraded my Laptop to build 1809 and the issue was fixed.